# Is rule method with assumption discharge deprecated in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I profit of this occassion to promote [this webpage](https://svhol.pbmichel.com/) explaining very nicely the inner workings of rule, erule, drule and frule.

However, I noticed that method rule(k) seems to not work in current Isabelle (in contrast to for instance drule(k). Take the example:

> lemma "A ⟹ A ∨ B"
> apply (rule(1) disjI1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual (Isar-ref) for Isabelle 2020, section 9.2, states that the method `rule` accepts exactly one argument `thms`. However, the methods `erule`, `drule` and `frule` have an additional optional argument `(nat)`:

> The optional natural number argument (default 0) specifies additional
> assumption steps to be performed here.